# Wireless Client to Ethernet Bridge with Vyatta

Tags: vyatta

I am trying to configure Vyatta to act as a wifi to ethernet bridge. I am currently doing this with my windows desktop but want to move it to a dedicated Vyatta box. I have a typical linksys wireless router that operates as my access point. The wireless card in the Vyatta box works just fine and is able to connect when it is configured as a normal wireless client. When I create the bridge between eth0 and wlan0, clients on the lan "behind" Vyatta still can't connect. If I restart Vyatta in this state, it will also not get an IP address from the wireless network any longer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my config:

```
vyatta@Vinz-Clortho:~$ show configuration 
interfaces { 
    bridge br0 { 
        aging 300 
        hello-time 2 
        max-age 20 
        priority 0 
        stp false 
    } 
    ethernet eth0 { 
        bridge-group { 
            bridge br0 
        } 
        duplex auto 
        hw-id 00:0d:60:c4:e5:cc 
        smp_affinity auto 
        speed auto 
    } 
    loopback lo { 
    } 
    wireless wlan0 { 
        address dhcp 
        bridge-group { 
            bridge br0 
        } 
        mode g 
        security { 
            wpa { 
                mode both 
                passphrase **************** 
            } 
        } 
        ssid SRT 
        type station 
    } 
} 
service { 
    ssh { 
        port 22 
        protocol-version v2 
    } 
} 
system { 
    host-name Vinz-Clortho 
    login { 
        user vyatta { 
            authentication { 
                encrypted-password **************** 
            } 
            level admin 
        } 
    } 
    ntp-server 0.vyatta.pool.ntp.org 
    package { 
        auto-sync 1 
        repository community { 
            components main 
            distribution stable 
            password **************** 
            url http://packages.vyatta.com/vyatta 
            username "" 
        } 
    } 
    syslog { 
        global { 
            facility all { 
                level notice 
            } 
            facility protocols { 
                level debug 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    time-zone US/Pacific 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using static IP's for the Vyatta appliance? Also it's been a while since I used Vyatta but I'm almost certain I had to define routes between the interfaces to get it to work.

Comment: Yea. I tried setting statics on all the interfaces including the bridge, as well as different combinations of with and without. I haven't done anything with routes though. The way I understand it, a bridge looks invisible to the hosts on either side. I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Go. Turns out this is not yet possible. From the vyatta forums:

> In general linux does not support
>   bridging wireless in station mode. 
>   The problem is that wireless is
>   internally point-to-point based and 
>   doing bridging requires MAC address
>   spoofing.

Comment: This is possible if you are using something like dd-wrt.